# Postback URL in Asp Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a repeater with which I am able to display item. Here the code:

```
<asp:Repeater 
             ID="rptHardware"
             runat="server">
             <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="Hardware">
                    <h1><%#Eval("Name") %></h1>
                    <br />
                    <asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# "/uploadedimg/" + Eval("ImageName") %>' Width="70%" />
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>


         </asp:Repeater>
```

I want to go in a detail page when I click on an item. Where do I put the postback URL? This is what I came up with.

```
PostBackUrl='<%#Eval("Hardware_ID","bookingdetails.aspx?id={0}")%>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can put it on H1 tag of Name section as well like below

```
 <asp:Repeater 
                 ID="rptHardware"
                 runat="server">
                 <ItemTemplate>
                    <div class="Hardware">
                        <a href='bookingdetails.aspx?id=<%#Eval("Hardware_ID")%>'><h1><%#Eval("Name") %></h1></a>
                        <br />
                        <asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# "/uploadedimg/" + Eval("ImageName") %>' Width="70%" />
                    </div>
                </ItemTemplate>


             </asp:Repeater>
```